# ReferenceError: replaceAllInRange_ is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

can someone help with this short piece of script - I keep getting the error "ReferenceError: replaceAllInRange_ is not defined"

```
function RemoveOutdatedIssueSummaries() 
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const range = ss.getRange('OpenCasesSummary!I:I');
  let numReplaces = replaceAllInRange_(range, 'Awaiting Scheduling', 'Check Status')
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

I have tried various ranges for the range, always with the same error.

This all new to me so an explanation of why I am getting that error as well as reasoning for any solution would be very helpful and help me to learn - I appreciate it.

Comment: As the error says, `replaceAllInRange_` is not defined. It seems to be a custom function  written by someone, which is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function replaceAllInRange_(rg,needle,replacement) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  return ss.getRange(rg).createTextFinder(needle).replaceAllWith(replacement);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, however I don't understand what to do with this (total scripting noob here lol) - do I replace rg with the range eg OpenCasesSummary!I:I and then 'needle' and 'replacement' with the text I want to remove/replace?

Comment: Its ok ive gone down a different route with this so no longer need help on this one :)